# Ensuring a smooth node-add routine

Tags: nodes

I am building a site in Drupal 8, where users can add training programs. An example of such a program could look something like this:

[image: Dummy workout]

The way I see it, I will need 3 node types:
Node type 1: **Program** (with a **Set** entity reference)
Node type 2: **Set** (with a **Exercise** entity reference)
Node type 3: **Exercise**

When adding a **Program** node-type, it can have multiple **Set** entity references. When adding a **Set**, - it will need a **Exercise** entity reference.

But how to ensure a smooth "Program" adding routine? So when adding a set to a program, the user will be sent back to the program after creating the needed Set-node.

I hope my description makes sense. Any ideas?

Comment: [Inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)?

Comment: This can be done in many ways and based in different opinions the solution might vary, therefore this question is off topic here. But try to look into the paragraphs module, I think that would be an easy way to do what you want. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Clive. This module is perfect, exactly what I needed!